# How to add to html <a> tag onclick event with PHP and call the function in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This question maybe is little bit strange but I need to learn it asap.

I have a HTML file which is called `upgrade.view.php` here is the piece of code that I am on working on:

```
    <form role="form" method="get" action='index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeChosen'>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <ul name="S_PRODUCT" id="S_VARIABLE">

            <?php                 
                 if (isset($oldProduct) && isset($arrayUpgrade)){
                     foreach ($arrayUpgrade as $value) {
                         $pro = $value->getnewProduct(); //                           
                    echo '<li><a href="index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeChosen" onclick="searchSN(this); return false;">'.$pro->getName().'</a></li>';                              
                }
            ?>   

            </ul>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

//which closes the main DIV

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?= PATH_VIEWS_INCLUDES_URL ?>js/upgrade/upgrade.js"></script>
```

On the other hand I am trying to call the JS function from `upgrade.js` where I have this function:

```
 function searchSN(elem) {        
        var a = elem.innerHTML;
        alert(a);

    }
```

Finally in my separated PHP file I have this function:

```
     public function upgradeChosen() {
                $selectedVariable = $_GET['S_PRODUCT'];
                echo 'The Price is:'." ". $selectedVariable;   
                include $this->getPrintedView();    
            }
```

As updated version of the question I am getting the on click event from the `<A>` tag but not the value the value of says undefined value.

I have updated the question so that maybe it makes it more understandable what I am trying to achieve.

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you try by function searchSN() {

    var a = document.getElementById("S_VARIABLE").value;
    alert(a);

}

Comment: It is getting the id however not the value do i need to add value tag to li or a tag ? thanks for your help

Comment: can you please elaborate it a little furthur? I can't get you :(

Comment: in the upgrade.view.php I have a for loop which populates the <li><a> tag with echo command and as can be seen it is all in <form> tag trying to get clicked value from JS function which is searchSN but for some reason i can not get the a tag's value from the JavaScript function (searchSN)... on the other hand i need to ask is it possible to achieve the click event from php function php file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this ?

```js
function searchSN(elem) {        
    var a = elem.innerHTML;
    alert(a);
}
```

```html
<form class="" role="form" method="get" action='index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeChosen'>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <ul name="S_PRODUCT" id="S_VARIABLE" >

        <li><a href="index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeChosen" onclick="searchSN(this); return false;">test</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button id='choose_product' type="submit" class='btn btn-default'><i class='icon-rocket'>Submit</i></button> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Basically i am not after getting the value with submit button submit button is for something else.....  is it possible to do it inside the echo ? because i want it to be inside the echo that is how i am printing the list. many thanks

Comment: I did the update like this  
echo '<li><a href="index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeChosen" onclick="searchSN(this); return false;">'.$pro->getName().'</a></li>';
function searchSN(elem) {
    
    var a = elem.innerHTML;
    alert(a);
    
}
still not getting the value inside the a tag

Comment: @SerhanKhan remove `onclick="searchSN();"` in `<ul name="S_PRODUCT" id="S_VARIABLE" onclick="searchSN();"`

Comment: Yes i did removed it :) but still really interesting it is not getting value

Comment: @SerhanKhan update your 1st post with new code please, cause it should by working...

Comment: @SerhanKhan and by the way, do you at least get the alert pop-up ? (if not, then it mean your JS file is not loaded, try to put the JS straight in the bottom of your html

Comment: yes i am getting the alert message thanks for it.,,,

Comment: @SerhanKhan try to clean your cache (ctrl + F5), it can be because you still use your old JS function

Comment: many thanks for your help the problem is solved i will mark it as a solution cheers thank you